# Pixel by pixel comparison in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, pixel

I have attempted to write a surface water detection program in GEE using the NDWI, with otsu thresholding and canny edge filtering. I would like to evaluate my approach and I was thinking of using the JRC surface water dataset. I am able to show map these 2 layers of water. However how can I do a pixel by pixel comparison between these 2 layers in GEE.

Both layers are simple white for water and black for land.
Pixel value of 1 = water and pixel value 0 = land.

Example images
[image]

Comment: You can add one image to another using `addBands` and then use `ee.Image.sample` to get the data in both images for each pixel. Then you can do a pixel by pixel comparison.

Comment: it'd be better if you share some code. What have you tried? How do you want to compare the layers? visually?